# Hive - How to calculate if all records inside a groupby have the same value in a specific column?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am grouping by records base on one column. What I want to know if all of these records has got the same value in another column.

So far I achieve this with the following logic, which I believe is too complex:

```
select number,
       if(flagSum = 0 OR flagSum = groupedrecords, "AllSame", "SomeDifferent") as AllIndicatorEqual
from
(select number,
       sum(if(flag = 'Y', 1, 0)) as flagSum,
       count(*) as groupedrecords
from table
where number = '1234' 
group by number
)tab
```

So basically I group by `number`, and check if all records grouped has got the same `flag` value.

Is there a more efficient way to calculate this?

Comment: Uff sorry, that was a mistake, I will edit the question

Comment: Actually, I do not see what is too complex in your query. Subquery does not affect performance because optimizer transforms it to the single map-reduce step.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably skip a subquery by using a distinct count :

```
select 
  number, 
  if(count(distinct flag) = 1, "AllSame", "SomeDifferent") as AllIndicatorEqual 
from table
group by number;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20e024/6